# Where find ascii symbols for spades heart clover tile

Tags: html, ascii

I'm doing a card game algorithm and I want to use ascii symbols for cards. But impossible to find these symbols. Would you have them?

thank you

Comment: Those aren't ASCII. But that's okay, you aren't using ASCII. HTML uses [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html). (ASCII is used only in very specialized contexts. Most references to it are incorrect.)

Comment: it's not? so what is it ?

Comment: HTML uses Unicode, just like Java, .NET, VB4, NTFS, JavaScript, CSS, XML, Python 3, Win32 API, VBA, ....

Comment: ah thank you for this information ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck): clubs (♣), diamonds (♦), hearts (♥) and spades (♠)

Comment: the most beautiful ! do you have one ?